# Add a record to a 'has_and_belongs_to_many' join table in a select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, `rental` and `project`:

```
 class Rental < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :deals
 end
```

and

```
 class Project < ApplicationRecord
     has_and_belongs_to_many :rentals
 end
```

`Rentals` has a `show.html.erb` page, which is public and pre-seeded based on data about an apartment rental (e.g. `localhost:3000/rentals/1`) . When a user is logged in, I want them to add the `Rental` they are viewing (e.g. `id:1`) to a specific `Project`. I watched a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised) and set up the associations.

What is the best way to build a select box of all `Projects` associated with a user to display on the `Rental` `show.html.erb` page, and add a record to the `Rental` and `Project` JoinTable? There should be some Controller and View work, but I cannot post records to that Rentals Projects JoinTable.

*EDIT, I FIGURED OUT A SOLUTION*

What I ended up doing was the following:

1) In the View, using an options_from_collection_for_select wrapped within a form tag, :method => :patch gave me the options

2) In the Routes file, I created a new entry to the `rentals` resource that I referenced in the View:

```
 resource :rentals 
     member do 
       patch 'add_to_project'
     end
 end
```

and 3) in the Rentals Controller, I added the following to a new method `add_to_project` that grabbed the project's option Id from the select box in the view, and added it to the collection this way:

project.rentals << rental

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: My feeling is that this is asking a lot. Have you looked at the docs for nested forms? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/form_helpers.html#nested-forms (5.0 guide) Also, would this be on an edit view rather than a show view?

Comment: @DouglasLovell yeah it is a lot. I've found some good stuff here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226363/associate-two-already-existing-objects-using-has-and-belongs-to-many